# Running an API, if I correct a content-type header will that break things for customers?

Tags: http, http-headers

We're running an API with quite a few people using it. Due to some legacy clumsiness on my part, one of the endpoints is returning the **wrong content-type header**, `js` when it should be `json`. My question is, if we fix this by swapping to return the correct value, how badly could it mess things up for our existing customers? Or to put it another way, would you expect many different HTTP client libraries to throw fatal errors when seeing such a change?

We're trying to decide if this is a change which we can just go ahead and make without sweating it too much, or we should carefully email all users and announce a multi-year deprecation period ...or something in between.

It probably depends a bit on what kind of different HTTP clients are in use, so I took a look at user agents. Answer: a lot of different ones! Here's some of the top ones:

*"okhttp/3.2.0", "python-requests/2.10.0", "Ruby", "python-requests/2.7.0", "Mozilla/5.0", "Java/1.8.0_91", "python-requests/2.4.3", "okhttp/3.3.0", "Lucee", "Dalvik/2.1.0", "Google-HTTP-Java-Client/1.21.0", "PHP_appname", "NativeHost", "Java/1.7.0_67", "Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE", "Dalvik/1.6.0", "Web-sniffer/1.1.0", "unirest-objc/1.1"*

Various different mobile and server side language libraries. Mostly not browsers running javascript, but some of those too.

Most people don't seem to notice that the content-type is wrong, but every now and then a new support request pops up complaining about this issue, so we'd like to fix it.

Comment: I would assume that clients that work correctly with an incorrect content-type header won't stop working once you set the correct one, but you know what they say about assumptions. So test, communicate your changes to your user base in advance and/or built in some additional logic that if a certain client does break, you can detect that particular client and keep returning the incorrect content-type header (or do the reverse, return the correct one for those clients that generate support tickets and keep everything the same for current users/user-agents).

Comment: mandatory xkcd: https://xkcd.com/1172/

Comment: Aren't you versioning your API?

Comment: We only have a major version number for the whole API which we would only look to bump in a few years time when we make some fairly major restructurings. At that point we'd fix this issue of course, but... feels like we may never do this. It's one of _those_ version numbers.

Answer (score 30):

> how badly could it mess things up for our existing customers?

It could completely sink their battleships if they've written code that relies on this *Content-Type* being incorrect.

I would not expect the libraries to throw errors, but I expect that in some cases strict libraries have had their behavior overridden to handle the incorrect MIME type.

If your API has a version/revision value in a request field somewhere, raise it, and in the new version return the correct type but continue to return the incorrect type in the older versions. If you don't have such a request field, now is a good time to add one.

Comment: +1 already for a good hyperbole

Comment: I'm going to have to disagree with the suggested versioning technique. Supporting old versions of the api can make sense, but the maintainence overhead of allowing api users to requests arbitrary old buggy versions of your api is simply not going to be worthwhile.

Comment: Often you don't have a choice.  Customers given an "update or leave" ultimatum may decide on the latter, good in principle, bad in practice.  The old version can be retired over time.

Comment: +1 vor versioning the requests, though you may want to check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_versioning for further information.

Comment: @WinstonEwert: Of course it is worthwhile. People specify which API version they want to use, then their program doesn't spontaneously combust in the time between you updating your API and them updating their program. If you don't do this, you automatically break _every_ current and historical release of your clients' code when you change your interface. And that's a dreadful way to run a service.

Comment: Yes I think there's decisions to weigh up, which will depend on our appetite for this overhead of old buggy versions (this certainly exists and is a consideration for us, you're right), versus the obvious desire to keep existing customers happy. My question was not so much about versioning approaches, but about whether/to what extent this is going to be a problem for customers.Let's say we were to just flip the content-type value (Seems that extreme caution-free approach is not advisable) who can give me an educated guess at how much "spontaneous combustion" would actually occur?

Comment: This seems like a very good point by way: *"I expect that in some cases strict libraries have had their behavior overridden to handle the incorrect mime-type"* My hunch (as an answer to the whole question) is that the vast majority of client libraries will be fine with this, but this is a concern. Some customers may have pro-actively worked around this, and swapping will then break it for them. I wonder how much of that has happened.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, that's not what I meant. I even said that "supporting old versions of the api can make sense." If you are going to make backwards incompatible change to your api, its a really good idea. But any change or bug fix might break users of your api in unexpected ways. It is not worth the extra complexity to have different version numbers for every fix or change. (As witnessed by the fact that most online apis only have a major version number, and make minor backwards compatible changes and bug fixes without changing that number.)

Comment: @WinstonEwert: You said _"the maintainence overhead of allowing api users to requests arbitrary old buggy versions of your api is simply not going to be worthwhile"_ which is false.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, you are misreading me. See the key phrase in what I said: "arbitrary old buggy versions of your api"

Comment: @WinstonEwert: I'm not misreading it. I read what you said, and I disagree with it, for the reasons previously outlined.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, do you ensure that when somebody requests version 35 of your api, that every single bug that exists in version 35 is still present?

Comment: @WinstonEwert: No, if somebody requests version 35 of your API, you must present version 35 of the API, as documented. Period. Nobody says you need to recreate old implementation bugs. But **if there is an old bug _in the version 35 API_ then, yes, that is part of the version 35 API and you must honour it when requested to do so**.

Comment: _"you must honour it when requested to do so"_.  Or cautiously deprecate within that version. Or decide that the fix is sufficiently non-breaking that you can just do it (Take the extreme joke case in this xkcd http://xkcd.com/1172 I think that shows that there's certainly a point at which most reasonable people would decide that it's not a breaking fix)

Answer (score 11):

> Would you expect many different HTTP client libraries to throw fatal
>   errors when seeing such a change?

No. Every HTTP client library I'm familiar with will ignore the content-type header unless the programmer specifically reads that header and does something with it. I can imagine a library where the content-type: application/json automatically causes a json parser to get involved but I don't know of any case where that actually happens.

> Most people don't seem to notice that the content-type is wrong, but
>   every now and then a new support request pops up complaining about
>   this issue, so we'd like to fix it.

How did they notice the incorrect header? It might be worth looking at that, because if the incorrect header was actually causing them problems they clearly weren't just ignoring it, and they might have problems if it is fixed.

Comment: [My answer has an example where that would actually happen](http://serverfault.com/a/793706/236470).

Comment: If you use jQuery `$.ajax` and don't specify the `dataType:` option, it infers the response type from the `Content-type` header. So if it's `application/json`, it will automatically parse it before passing it on to the caller.

Answer (score 6):

Too hard to tell without getting sign-off from all of your clients. I would suggest taking one of the following two approaches to upgrade your API to v.Next.

1. Extend existing API. Add a query string or some other variable to your API that signifies to use v.Next. For all requests using that variable, use the updated content-type.
2. Run a Staging or Pre-Production instance of your API in parallel with your current API. It should be nearly identical to production. Even using the same back-end. Although this one will have the proposed changes for v.Next.

In either scenario, communicate to your clients the changes you'd like to make and the target cutover date/time. Encourage them to test well before the target date to ensure there is no service disruption.

Ensure you have a dedicated page detailing the changes made to v.Next. This should be included in the communications sent out to your clients. If you've discussed any fixes with existing clients, include those on this page.

Finally, tread the line between over-communicating with your customers and spamming them. These notifications can be easily overlooked as more immediate/urgent priorities come up.

FWIW, if things are currently working I wouldn't worry too much about it. If for example you find that this causes a significant security vulnerability then that would be a great reason to push out this change. Otherwise I'd wait for something more pressing to include this change with.

Comment: Thanks. It's not the answer I wanted to hear, but maybe you're right. We just need to introduce the change very cautiously. Is it "Too hard to tell" though? I guess I was hoping some folks would have experience of the likely impact of this particular kind of content-type header change (leaving aside the more generic points about versioning cautiously)

Answer (score 5):

Here's an example of a library (well, single command) that this would break:

The [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) cmdlet [`Invoke-RestMethod`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849971.aspx) acts differently with JSON. If the result of the request is JSON, XML, or ATOM/RSS (and I think it's based on the header), it parses/deserializes it and returns native objects, otherwise it returns the raw data.

So the existing code would be written to deal with a string (perhaps by passing it to [`ConvertFrom-Json`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849898.aspx)), and would all of a sudden start failing.

Comment: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/10/21/invokerestmethod-for-the-rest-of-us/ confirms the theory that this looks at the header.

Answer (score -2):

I have noticed two consequences:

1. Some client libraries will not process the response properly. For example, the response returns a string instead of json or an array.
2. Compression is not always applied.

Comment: Surely it's the one sending the data, not the one receiving it, which applies compression?